# jQuery: Prevent an auto-embedded different version of jQuery conflicting with the code.

Tags: jquery

Some embeddable scripts include jQuery on their own to work. Because of this, a website that has been coded for a particular version of jQuery may break. How can this conflict be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the [`$.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method for this. It lets you assign jQuery to whatever other variable you like:

```
var myJQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

You can then use jQuery with your new variable. For example:

```
var divs = myJQ('div');
```

While this works, you probably want to be able to use the nice `$` symbol.

No problem. Just put all your code in [an IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), and pass in your copy of jQuery:

```
var myJQ = jQuery.noConflict();

(function ($){
    // now just use the $ sign...
    var divs = $('div');
}(myJQ));
```